# Test if a coordinate (x,y) is inside a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix **D** as follows:

```
  D=[ 
    1 2  
    3 4  
    5 6
       ]
```

What I want to do is to test if my coordinate at position `(ii,jj)` belongs to a one line in **D**.

In other terms, I have a for loop, and inside it, I want to increase a variable by 1 if the condition that verifies "(ii & jj) belongs to a line of **D**" is true.

For example, we can do this manually:

```
var = 0;
for ii = 1: 20
    for jj = 1:30
        if((ii==1 && jj==2) || (ii==3 && jj==4) || (ii==5 && jj==6))
var = var + 1;
end
    end
        end
```

This is straightforward since the matrix **D** contains only `3` lines. But in my work, I have of about `1000` lines, so **D** is of size `1000*2`. In this case, I have to find a method which can do the same job as I have written above but automatically and in a very fast manner. But how?

In fact one can think to use `ismember`, for example:

```
var = 0;
for ii = 1 : 20
    for jj = 1 : 30
        if(ismember(ii, D(:,1)) && ismember(jj, D(:,2)))
var = var + 1;
end
    end
        end
```

But this is not correct, since for example, the code just above can find `ii=1` and `jj=6`, but in this case `(ii,jj)` will be `(1,6)` and which does not belong to any of `(1,2)`, `(3,4)` and `(5,6)`.

Please, any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Please, for readabilities sake, indent your `if` and `for` statements properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `'rows'` input to [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to check if your array is a row within the matrix

```
tf = ismember([ii,jj], D, 'rows');
```

You can also check multiple values of `ii` and `jj` at once

```
% Create all permutations of ii and jj
[ii,jj] = ndgrid(1:20, 1:30);

% Test all of these permutations to see which ones are in D
tf = ismember([ii(:), jj(:)], D, 'rows');
```

And then to compute `var`

```
var = sum(tf);
```

If you are dealing with non-integers, you should use `ismembertol` instead to deal with possible floating point errors.